# Using qsort() in C and skipping specific sets of character

Tags: c, qsort

```
#define alen(x) ((sizeof x) / (sizeof *x))

typedef struct {
    char *movie_title;
    int minutes;
    float price;
} DVD;

int
main()
{
    DVD movies[10] = {
        { "The Dark Knight", 153, 14.99},
        { "Iron Man", 126, 12.99},
        { "Batman Begins", 141, 9.99},
        { "Batman Returns", 126, 9.99},
        { "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles", 87, 7.99},
        { "The Incredible Hulk", 114, 12.99},
        { "X-Men", 104, 12.99},
        { "Spider-Man", 121, 14.99},
        { "Fantastic Four", 106, 14.99},
        { "Captain America", 124, 19.99},
    };

    qsort(movies, alen(movies), sizeof *movies, tcomp);

    printf("Movies sorted: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < alen(movies); i++)
        printf("%s\n", movies[i].movie_title);
}

int
tcomp (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return strcmp(((DVD*)a)->movie_title,((DVD*)b)->movie_title);
}
```

When sorting the movie titles with the function tcomp and qsort I need to forgot about "A", "An", and "The" in movie titles. Can somebody help me figure out how do to this in an elegant manner?

Comment: strip out before comparing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only concerned about prefix words, then before you do the compare, adjust the pointers

```
char* skip_irrelvant(char* s)
{
   while(*s == ' ') s++;
   if(strnicmp(s, "The ", 4)==0) s+=4;
   return s;
}


    int tcomp (const void * a, const void * b)
    {
       char* s1 = ((DVD*)a)->movie_title;
       char* s2 = ((DVD*)b)->movie_title;
       s1 = skip_irrelvant(s1);
       s2 = skip_irrelvant(s2);

       return strcmp(s1, s2);
    }
```

Comment: It says implicit declaration of function "strnicmp" is invalid in C99? I included the <string.h> header so do you have any idea why?!

Comment: Just used strcmp in any case! Thanks!

Comment: oh right, sorry,  in which case, convert it to lower first, otherwise it will be case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to strip your wanted ignored words out of a temporary copy of the name before  the comparison?

Then simply compare the processed names.

I imagine this should be simple enough to implement such a function by splitting by spaces, and then making sure the word is a "valid word" before shoving the word into the output string.